# SAS - Ods tagsets.excelxp & proc report - column with formula not aligned to center

Tags: sas, proc-report

I need your help!

I'm trying to create an output, in SAS, with proc report.
Although i use in options center_vertical & center_horizontal as you can see below, column "Failing Rule" (that is computed) in output isn't centered, but aligned to the left.
Can anyone help?

```
options missing = "";
ods listing close;
ods tagsets.excelxp style=mystyle file="./Pre-Model_Diagnostic_&ProjectName..xml"
options(Sheet_Name="Pre-Model Diagnostic" hidden_columns="&HideCol"
        autofit_height='yes' autofilter='all' frozen_rowheaders='2' frozen_headers='yes' width_fudge='1.25' center_vertical='yes' center_horizontal='yes' )

.
.
.
.
    define OverallRule_Fail  /"Fail/Rule"    center ;   
    define OverallRule_Watch  /"Warning/Rule"  center ; 
    define FailingRule   /"Failing/Rule"   center style(column)={tagattr='Formula:RC[-2]&char(10)&RC[-1]'}  ;

compute FailingRule;
if missing(OverallRule_Fail)=0  
then call define(_col_,"style","style={background=%RGBHEX(210,073,042) foreground='black' fontfamily=calibri}");
else if missing(OverallRule_Fail)=1 and missing(OverallRule_Watch)=0 
then call define(_col_,"style","style={background=%RGBHEX(238,182,169) foreground='black' fontfamily=calibri}");
endcomp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `FailingRule` a character field.

```
compute FailingRule /character length=20;
```

That seems to get it to work for me.